# Having issues while connecting H2 in memory database using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, h2

I am trying to connect an H2 in memory DB through Selenium webdriver. I am using a H2 in-memry database with URL "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb".

I am using the below jdbc url to connect to the DB:
"jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"

However, it is throwing "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException" error with table not found. Plz let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: It seems that you got a connection. But you have an empty db (error => table not found) so you have to init your db on start up before your test can access it.

Comment: @Vitali, Thanks. I have created the connection object using, Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "sa","{the_password}"); ....what else is required to init the DB in selenium? Plz advice

Comment: The H2 in memory db instance is deployed in cloud and I want to get the existing table details from there, using selenium. Is it possible for in-memory DB?

Comment: I'm not sure if selenium is the right tool for your problem. So you are running in-memory db in a cloud but who is creating all schema data in your db? And what is the purpose of selenium. If you like to check table details just connect to db and use sql statements.

Comment: The tables are already created in cloud and I can access that manually using the cloud url (opening in a browser)....I am using selenium to automate the DB tasks. Like I want to add/delete some rows from the existing table using automated selenium scripts, instead of manually doing it

Comment: Then selenium is the wrong tool for you. It would be easier and faster to write a script with a language of your choice which does the job without opening a browser and click around with selenium...

Comment: Selenium-java has the utility to connect to a DB and perform DB tasks. So that is why I am using selenium-java for this. But stuck in the issue as it is not getting the table.